# Source of "Der Tod ist die letzte Feste dem Freien, deren Tor immer offen steht."

Tags: poetry

There is an epigraph, poem or similar, where something like

> Der Tod ist die letzte Feste dem Freien, deren Tor immer offen steht.

is written (but unfortunately I do not remember the details). What is the title/author/accurate text of that epigraph/poem/..., please? (I suspect the author to be Ernst Jünger.)

Edit: [Olaf's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4751/23) was not the text I thought about, but it is interesting to see this, thanks! "Draußen vor der Tür" was created at the end of 1946/start of 1947, while "Das Abenteuerliche Herz" is from 1938. Thus W. Borchert might have known E. Jünger's text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "... das Todestor, als das wichtigste der unsichtbaren Tore, für uns
>   alle, ohne Unterscheidung, Tag und Nacht, geöffnet ... Er nannte den
>   Tod die wundersamste Reise, die der Mensch vermöchte, ein wahres
>   Zauberstück, die Tarnkappe aller Tarnkappen ... die letzte und
>   unangreifbare Burg aller Freien und Tapferen."

aus: "Das Abenteuerliche Herz", 1938, in: Ernst Jünger: Sämtliche Werke in 18 Bänden, Band 9, Essays III: Das Abenteuerliche Herz. Klett-Cotta, Stuttgart 1979, ISBN 3-12-904191-5 und ISBN 3-12-904691-7 (enthält beide Fassungen).

Answer (score 2):

You've probably googled quite a bit, with no results, so let me add another wild guess to yours.

[Wolfgang Borchert](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Borchert), who was born after Ernst Jünger and died before him and who created remarkable stuff in his short life, wrote a drama named [Draussen vor der Tür](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drau%C3%9Fen_vor_der_T%C3%BCr) in which in *Szene 5* Beckmann and the Straßenfeger (road sweeper) - who is the death - [meet](http://www.scribd.com/doc/50799349/Borchert-Wolfgang-Draussen-vor-der-Tuer).

Their words don't really match those in your question, but there is a resemblance in the tone:

> BECKMANN: Tod, Tod, laß mir die Tür offen. Tod, mach die Tür nicht zu. Tod –
>
> STRASSENFEGER: Meine Tür steht immer offen. Immer. Morgens. Nachmittags. Nachts. Im Licht und im Nebel. Immer ist meine Tür offen.

And so on. Maybe that's what you remembered?

Comment: would have been my guess to.

Comment: @Olaf: I found it, see https://german.stackexchange.com/a/49302/1704